# JGit example for MergeCommand

Tags: java, git, github, egit, jgit

I'm newbie to JGit and am trying to create a program to perform git operations through JGit.

Is there any good example for JGit Merge, I've looked at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/ but there only CheckMergeStatusOfCommit.java available that does not full fill my requirement.

**Scenario:-** I have a file on my **remote** say "*abc.txt*" as well as in my **working repo**. 
File is having conflicts, since on same line there is different text on remote and working repository.

How could i get the latest changes from my remote and merge them with the changes from working repo, I need changes from both (remote and working repo).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a corresponding sample as part of my [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) at [MergeChanges.java](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/MergeChanges.java), the relevant code-snippet is something like this:

```
            ObjectId mergeBase = repository.resolve("changes");
            System.out.println("Merge-Results for id: " + mergeBase + ": " + merge);
            for (Map.Entry<String,int[][]> entry : merge.getConflicts().entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey());
                for(int[] arr : entry.getValue()) {
                    System.out.println("value: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
                }
            }
```

Update: Edited the snippet to show how merge-conflicts are returned, see also the [JavaDoc for getConflicts()](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/MergeResult.html#getConflicts())